# assign a list to a keyed dictionary in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have an incoming list in Tcl that is actually the values to a keyed list.

Something like this

```
set list1 [list value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9]
set keys [list key1 key2 key3]
```

I'd like to assign list1 into a keyed array by the keys in the keys list in Tcl.

is this the best method to do so?  Or is there a more elegant method?

```
 foreach {a b c} $list1 {
      dict lappend mydict key1 $a
      dict lappend mydict key2 $b
      dict lappend mydict key3 $c
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd be more tempted to do:

```
foreach {a b c} $list1 {
    foreach k $keys v [list $a $b $c] {
        dict lappend mydict $k $v
    }
}
```

Either that, or to expand out the list of keys to the length of the incoming list before using a simpler double `foreach`:

```
foreach k [lrepeat [expr {[llength $list1]/[llength $keys]}] {*}$keys] v $list1 {
    dict lappend mydict $k $v
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if these are more elegant (or robust) than what you're already doing.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you sure that isn't a typo in your second code snippet?  Shouldn't that be $keys not $list1 in the lrepeat command?

Comment: @Jonjilla Err, yes. Fixed. (Didn't have time to run the code before leaving for work, so a bug crept in…)